# nginx vhost error "duplicate default server"

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, centos7, node.js

I have a problem settingup name based vhosts on a CentOS 7 box I have set up. When I try to start up, I get the following error:

Dec 07 20:55:28 li805-37 nginx[7284]: nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/website-one.conf:2

Here is the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" 

'
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and the vhost configs, first `website-one` which runs node:

```
upstream node_server {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website-one.com;

    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/webone/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/webone/error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://node_server;
    }

    location /public/ {
        root /opt/website-one;
    }
}
```

then `website-two` which is a static html site for now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website-two.com;

    access_log /var/log/webtwo/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/webtwo/error.log debug;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root /var/www/;
    }

}
```

Also I have tried greping for "default_server" in the `/etc/nginx` directory and the result just hit two commented out lines in `/etc/nginx/nginx.con` that I have removed for brevity.

Comment: The config files you've pasted don't correspond to the error message. Please check everything and make any necessary corrections to your question.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but those are all the config files and the error message specifically mentions the config I have pasted in. Is there something else that I'm not including tha tI should be?

Comment: I don't know what you haven't included. That's why I asked you to check that you've actually pasted the actual files.

Comment: Grep for "default_server". You have two of them, you can only have one (that's the short beginners version of the answer, it's not 100% correct).

Comment: I did grep default_server the only lines that come up are commented out nginx config none are in any of the conf files in the conf.d

Comment: The pasted configuration, beyond having missing elements doesn't seem coherent with what NGINX says. Your first server should have the listening directive on line 2 when it's on line 6 so the pasted configuration doesn't match the one NGINX is loading. Moreover, you list your nginx.conf like it's in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` which I imagine it isn't.

Comment: @Ginnungagap you're right the path was wrong, I've corrected that now its should be `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and the example server config is from the "configuring nginx" section of this site: https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/20/hosting-deploying-nodejs-centos.html

Comment: So I figured it out. I was not restarting the server correctly, in fact I was just checking the status over and over `sudo systemctl status -l nginx.service` after I correctly modified the config. Sorry for the wild goose chase.

Comment: Would you mind creating a separate answer with your findings and mark it as the solution then? This way the question will show up as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a total brain fart on my part. To begin with I tried to start nginx like so:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

when it failed I checked for an error message:

```
sudo systemctl status -l nginx.service
```

Then, after I had fixed the problem I looked to see if the error was still present by running `sudo systemctl status -l nginx.service` again, but without attempting to start the service, that command just gives me the last error! Therefore I was getting the same error despite having already fixed the problem. Remember folks, when changing nginx config, you have to *actually start the service* before you check for an error message.